# How to prove different execution order in an obvious way

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I'd like to demonstrate in a bluntly obvious way how this asynchronous sample:

```
Thing[] stuff = await Context.Things
    .Where(a => true)
    .ToArrayAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Beep");
```

will execute in a different order than they synchronous version:

```
Thing[] stuff = Context.Things
    .Where(a => true)
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("Boop");
```

I'd like to show that the second version **always** creates the array before the printout while the first one may perform differently.

Not sure how to do it obviously clear.

Comment: Both versions always create the array before the printout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd like to demonstrate in a bluntly obvious way how this asynchronous sample:
> will execute in a different order than they synchronous version

But you can't because both versions will create array before the `Console.WriteLine("Boop");`. In the first sample `await` will stop the method execution until the asynchronous operation will finish.

Such experiments are not that easy with db contexts because you will need some side effect. Much easier to use `Task.Delay` for async simulation;

Your first snippet can be changed to:

```cs
var array = await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500); // simulate db call
    Console.WriteLine("Array created");
    return new int[]{};
});

Console.WriteLine("Beep");
```

Then you can compare it with:

```cs
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500); // simulate db call
    Console.WriteLine("Array created");
    return new int[]{};
});

Console.WriteLine("Beep"); 

var array = await task;
```

As for trying to prove async nature of EF Core calls (1. assuming you are using this ORM 2. assuming that you are not querying Oracle database which AFAIK still does not provide truly async client) you will need to find a way to inject your side effect. For relatively easy way to do this you can look into [EF Core Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) or events like [`ChangeTracker.Tracked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/events) or just enabling logging and/or [using diagnostic listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/diagnostic-listeners).

For example (should work in EF7):

```cs
class ObjectCreatedLoggerInterceptor : IMaterializationInterceptor
{
    public object CreatedInstance(MaterializationInterceptionData materializationData, object entity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array element created");
        return entity;
    }
}

public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new ObjectCreatedLoggerInterceptor());
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Which will write `"Array element created"` every time an object is created by EF (query should return at least one record).

Comment: Hi there. I see that often in your writing you are using "cause" when you mean "because". The latter can be thought of as "be-the-cause" and it connects a statement on the left hand side with an explanation on the right hand side. I've repaired this several times - could you make an effort to re-check this when you find yourself reaching for this word?

Comment: @halfer yes, thank you. I'm trying to break out of this habit, but this takes time =(

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify first example as following to prove it.

```
var task = Context.Things
    .Where(a => true)
    .ToArrayAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Beep");
Thing[] stuff = await task;
```

In this example, ToArray will be executed after the console as task is awaited later on.

Comment: That doesn't prove that they run in a different order ([they don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175582/how-to-prove-different-execution-order-in-an-obvious-way#comment132657427_75175582)). That fundamentally *changes* how the async one runs so that they *do* run in a different order.

Comment: @madreflection This is exactly op is looking for, probably he wants to explain someone (probably students or coworkers) about how it looks in the code vs how it will actually execute.

Comment: No, they wanted to prove that *the examples given* execute in a different order. That's not provable because they don't.

Comment: *"You have to modify first example as following to prove it."* -- You can't prove a theorem by changing the theorem. In that case you have proved a different theorem, and the original theorem remains unproved.